# Change animation when is clicked on it, and then animate back when clicked on another image on touch jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

```js
$(".pen").click(function(){
           
    $(this).animate({height: '+70px'});
    $(this).css('padding-top' ,'10px');
    $(this).not.animate({height: '+60px'});
    $(this).not.css('padding-top' ,'20px');        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cntr" style="margin-left: 25px;">  
  
<img src="images/pen/red.png" id="red" class="stretch pen red" alt="" /> 
   
<img src="images/pen/orange.png" id="orange" class="stretch pen orange" alt="" />    

<img src="images/pen/yellow.png" id="yellow" class="stretch pen yellow" alt="" />    

<img src="images/pen/green.png" id="green" class="stretch pen green" alt="" />    

<img src="images/pen/blue.png" id="blue" class="stretch pen blue" alt="" /> 
   
<img src="images/pen/purple.png" id="purple" class="stretch pen purple" alt="" />    

<img src="images/pen/black.png" id="black" class="stretch pen black" alt="" />    

<img src="images/back.png" class="stretch undo " onClick="undoDraw();" alt="" style="padding-left: 10px;"/>

</div>
```

I have a pen tool slider in my phonegap application im using jquery mobile for framework. I like to switch the pens when selected it has to highlight and the other has to slide down. Im animating the image to give zoom effect and i dont know how to reverse it when another element is clicked. Kindly help me as im new to this

Comment: i think you need to change you code a bit like: instead of `$(this).not.animate({height: '+60px'});$(this).not.css('padding-top' ,'20px');  ` go for `$(".pen").not(this).animate({height: '+60px'});$(".pen").not(this).css('padding-top' ,'20px'); `

Comment: yes i got the answer, i did the same but i used $(".pen").not($(this)).animate({height: '+60px'}); and its coming

Comment: but my background is also moving with the animation any suggestion to keep it fixed?

Comment: Got fixed completely with the issues changed css styles.

Comment: thats great...`:)`!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".pen").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({height: '+70px'});
  $(this).css('padding-top' ,'10px');
  $(".pen").not($(this)).animate({height: '+60px'});
  $(".pen").not($(this)).css('padding-top' ,'20px');
});
```

Changed the not function into this and its working now

Thanks for the reply vijayP your reply is appreciatable